# No changes while displaying php file

Tags: php

I have this error I made changes in php file and I am trying to view it it doesn't show any changes in the browser. I have also included php files in index.php. The address that I am going to is localhost/lr/index.php I made login form and it doesn't show in the browser. I stopped apache and mysql and I restarted my laptop after tat I go to the address and still no changes it does not show log in form I made. BTW I am watching this videos from YouTube YouTube channel called phpacademy and playlist name is Login and Register.

Code

Login.php

```
<div class="widget">
<h2>Log in/Register</h2>
<div class="inner">
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <ul id="login">
            <li>
                Username:<br>
                <input type="text" name="username">
            </li>
            <li>
                Password:<br>
                <input type="password" name="username">
            </li>               
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in">
            </li>
            <li>
            </li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: I just submitted code the main one index.php I did not submitted it.

Comment: Can you show us some of the PHP code? Also, are you caching this page? You may need to empty your part of your browser cache if this is the case.

Comment: do lr folder exist , what do you see when you enter localhost/lr/index.php , try to void your index.php and write something and refresh browser !

Comment: That's just the HTML form. What's important is what's in the login.php code. Please post it.